# Rewrites to Mac OSX WebApp not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, restler, osx-server

I've created a WebApp on Mac OS X 10.9.  If I just go to something like the index.html it works fine, so I know the apache config there is working.  Now I'm trying to get a rewrite rule to work for Restler and am having issues.  My httpd.conf file looks like this:

```
Alias "/dts" "/Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/dts"
<Directory "/Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/dts">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes -MultiViews FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Now I want a path like https://myserver.com/dts/api/foo to redirect to the index.php file in the api directory, so I put a .htaccess file in the api subdirectory:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/dts/api

    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors On
</IfModule>
```

The last line of my rewrite log has the correct path showing:

```
(1) pass through /Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/dts/api/index.php
```

But what the browser returns is:

```
The requested URL /Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/dts/api/index.php was not found on this server.
```

If I do an ls -l of that path it's absolutely there.   What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A little more info, it looks like it's trying to start from the normal Apache root instead of the /Library path...i.e it's looking for /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/Library/Server/Web/Data/WebApps/dts/api and not finding it.

Comment: `RewriteBase /dts/api` should be enough